# How to pass custom class (subclass of QDialog) to other custom class (subclass of QObject) in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, subclass, qdialog, qobject

I am making a Qt project. To make it simplier, i decided to make a class `JsonPostSender`, it subclasses `QObject`. I have my login dialog, subclassing `QDialog`. I can't pass login dialog to `JsonPostSender` and i get the following error: `E0289 no instance of constructor "JsonPostSender::JsonPostSender" matches the argument list`. Is there anything wrong with my code? How can I fix that error?

My code:

JsonPostSender.h

```cpp
#include <QObject>
#include <qnetworkaccessmanager.h>
#include <qjsonobject.h>

class JsonPostSender : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    JsonPostSender(QObject* parent, QUrl url, QJsonObject json, void (*finishFunc)(QJsonObject));
    void sendPost();
    void onFinish(QNetworkReply* reply);
    ~JsonPostSender();

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
    QUrl url;
    QJsonObject json;
    void (*finishFunc)(QJsonObject);
};
```

JsonPostSender.cpp

```cpp
#include "JsonPostSender.h"
#include <qnetworkaccessmanager.h>
#include <qnetworkreply.h>
#include <qnetworkrequest.h>
#include <qjsondocument.h>

JsonPostSender::JsonPostSender(QObject *parent, QUrl url, QJsonObject json, void (*finishFunc)(QJsonObject))
    : QObject(parent), url(url), json(json), finishFunc(finishFunc)
{
    connect(&mgr, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &JsonPostSender::onFinish);
}

void JsonPostSender::sendPost() {
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
    QJsonDocument doc(json);
    QByteArray data = doc.toJson();
    QNetworkReply* reply = mgr.post(request, data);
}

void JsonPostSender::onFinish(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    qDebug() << "Finished";
    QJsonObject json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll()).object();
    finishFunc(json);
}

JsonPostSender::~JsonPostSender()
{}
```

loginForm.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_loginForm.h"
#include "qmessagebox.h"
#include "qprogressdialog.h"
#include "QtNetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.h"
#include "QtNetwork/qnetworkreply.h"
#include "qjsonobject.h"
#include "qjsondocument.h"

class loginForm : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    loginForm(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~loginForm();
    QString auth_token;

public slots:
    void setPasswordShow();
    void tryLogin();
    void onPostFinish(QJsonObject json);

private:
    Ui::loginFormClass ui;
};
```

loginForm.cpp (error at line 29)

```cpp
#include "loginForm.h"
#include "qmessagebox.h"
#include "qprogressdialog.h"
#include "QtNetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.h"
#include "QtNetwork/qnetworkreply.h"
#include "qjsonobject.h"
#include "qjsondocument.h"
#include "JsonPostSender.h"

loginForm::loginForm(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.showPassword, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &loginForm::setPasswordShow);
    connect(ui.buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::accepted, this, &loginForm::tryLogin);
    connect(ui.buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::rejected, this, &loginForm::reject);
}

void loginForm::tryLogin() {
    QJsonObject json;
    json["login"] = ui.loginInp->text();
    json["passord"] = ui.passwordInp->text();
    JsonPostSender sender(this /*<-- here*/, "http://localhost:8301/api/get_token",
        json, &loginForm::onPostFinish);
}

void loginForm::onPostFinish(QJsonObject json) {
    if (json["token"].isNull()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "error", json["error"].toString());
    }
    else {
        auth_token = json["token"].toString();
        QMessageBox::information(this, "success", "you're logged in");
        accept();
    }
}

void loginForm::setPasswordShow() {
    if (ui.showPassword->isChecked()) {
        ui.passwordInp->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::EchoMode::Normal);
    }
    else {
        ui.passwordInp->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::EchoMode::Password);
    }
}

loginForm::~loginForm()
{}
```

Comment: Look at the error message in the Output Tab and not the errors list. There should be more information on why the arguments for constructor does not match.

Comment: use signals and slots

Comment: I would argue that since you're just creating your JsonPostSender object on the stack, that you don't need to be passing a parent QObject pointer to its constructor at all. It will be deleted automatically when it goes out of scope. Maybe you have other use cases though.

Comment: It's not `QObject*` parameter that's the problem, it's `void (*finishFunc)(QJsonObject)`. `&loginForm::onPostFinish` doesn't match this type; it's of type `void (loginForm::*)(QJsonObject)` You may wish to read about plain function pointers vs pointers-to-member.